# Eclipse workspace wont start

Tags: eclipse

Well, my eclipse workspace wont start anymore, I stopped programming for a while, and then now I wanted to come back and I cant open my eclipse workspace, here is the log file: https://pastebin.com/ruyDTGCD

Ive tried removing workspace.iwo or whatever it was called but that didn't work, and I put it back again, and another one ive tried is putting javaw inside of the eclipse folder.

```
!SESSION 2019-07-08 09:25:37.875 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=4.7.0.I20170612-0950
java.version=9.0.4
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2019-07-08 09:25:58.212
!MESSAGE Application error
!STACK 1
org.eclipse.e4.core.di.InjectionException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/annotation/PostConstruct
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.internalMake(InjectorImpl.java:410)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.make(InjectorImpl.java:318)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts.ContextInjectionFactory.make(ContextInjectionFactory.java:162)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application.createDefaultHeadlessContext(E4Application.java:491)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application.createDefaultContext(E4Application.java:505)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application.createE4Workbench(E4Application.java:204)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.lambda$3(Workbench.java:614)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:336)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:594)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:148)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:151)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:388)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:243)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:653)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:590)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1499)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1472)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/annotation/PostConstruct
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.inject(InjectorImpl.java:124)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.internalMake(InjectorImpl.java:399)
    ... 23 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.annotation.PostConstruct cannot be found by org.eclipse.e4.core.di_1.6.100.v20170421-1418
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:433)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:395)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:387)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:150)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 25 more
```

basically you see the log file.

I just updated the log file now by renaming the old one, so I get a new one. This is everything in the log file.

Comment: This might be caused by DevStyle. If you able to open the workspace with the current version of Eclipse 2019-06 without additional plug-ins, report it to Genuitec.

Comment: Everything in the log is older than a year.

Comment: I just updated the log file now by renaming the old one, so I get a new one. I updated the log file on the page too.

Comment: Your Eclipse is too old to run with Java 9.

Comment: How do I change?

Comment: See https://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini#Specifying_the_JVM Or [download the current version from here (which works also with Java 9, 10, 11 and 12)](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/).

Answer (score 0):

The Eclipse `.metadata` folder contains a lot of information on how Eclipse is used and configured. This could possibly get corrupted somehow causing Eclipse not to start anymore.
To check whether this is the case just open up Eclipse on a complete fresh workspace. Eclipse should then generate a fresh `.metadata` folder and should at least start up again.
If the startup is successful one can think about importing the projects from the old workspace again and continue from there. Eclipse has to be reconfigured then.

Comment: There is a lot more than that that is lost by doing this. All your preferences for a start.

Comment: I think there is a glitch because I changed my windows account name from NarpZ to Narpzy.

Comment: I edited the post: I think I found out why, it happened because I changed my windows profile name from NarpZ to Narpzy and it is still thinking about the old directory, how do you change the directory again.

Comment: The log doesn't contain something serious. Please specify more details regarding " my eclipse workspace wont start anymore". If you want Eclipse to open/create workspace in specific folder you can use _-data_ argument : in the log you are using _-data C:\Users\NarpZ\another_

Comment: @Narpzy Hopefully you didn't follow the advice to delete the `.metadata` folder or at least, you made a backup. Can you start Eclipse with a new workspace (`eclipse -data <path_to_new_workspace>`)?

Comment: The recommendation to delete the `.metadata` folder can be found many times on stackoverflow.com but I have never found it on eclipse.org. Do you think it's because Stack Overflow people know more about Eclipse than the Eclipse developers?

Comment: I once wrote plugins for eclipse and destroyed my workspace multiple times. For me it worked best when cleaning metadata. Also sometimes you don’t want to collect state and therefore you could start eclipse with a -clean flag.

Comment: Whether you delete the metadata folder or you start with a new workspace you will end up with the same result :)

Comment: How do you start with a clean flag?

Comment: Make a new eclipse shortcut and modify this shortcut. https://help.eclipse.org/neon/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fmisc%2Fruntime-options.html But this makes you eclipse start with a fresh workspace every time. When developing plugins this might be a desired feature but as and end user you typically want eclipse to remember the settings you made.

Comment: nothing here worked, maybe it has something to with my eclipse version, im using Eclipse Oxygen 2017.

Comment: How many RAM does your machine have? You could check eclipse memory settings.

Comment: @Narpzy Eclipse Oxygen (4.7) is five releases behind the current release Eclipse 2019-06 (4.12) and no longer works with Java 9 or higher out-of-the-box. But you are using Java 8, so that is not the problem. It would also look different if there was not enough memory. The problem might be the DevStyle plug-in (which tries to patch Eclipse on start-up and which might fail). So please try to open the workspace with an Eclipse without additional plug-ins.

Comment: I have 16 gb's of ram, and I tried opening eclipse without the Devstyle thing, but it still shows the same error message: An error has occurred. See the log file C:\Users\NarpZ\another\.metadeta\.log.

Comment: Ok, could you please open up that eclipse on a complete fresh workspace which has no project. Does it open up?

Comment: Time to get a fresh eclipse then. And then just reimport and configure your project.

Comment: _"I tried opening eclipse without the Devstyle thing"_ - Could you please tell exactly what you did (Which Eclipse IDE package? Which version? With or without the restored `.metadata` folder?)? If you still get the same error message in the log file, you still run Eclipse with additional plug-ins.

Comment: I added as much on the log file as I could now.

Comment: Strage why is it doing `com.genuitec.eclipse.theming.ui` on a workspace with a deleted `.metadata` folder?

Comment: @Narpzy Look at the timestamps in the log, everything in it is older than a year. Maybe you are looking at the wrong place or the workspace is not writable. I'm sorry something is not working, but I can't help you without details and without you answering my questions.

Comment: @arnonuem Please delete your answer. If someone follows your advice and deletes the `.metadata` folder, data will be lost that might be important. If you don't believe, go try it yourself. Or rewrite your answer, and recommend a new workspace and then import from the old workspace. I hate to down-vote answers, but currently the answer is wrong and harmful.

Comment: ok - i will rephrase that - but this is how i solved my problems back then :)

Comment: @arnonuem Thanks. You lost data by doing this, even though you didn't notice the loss.

Comment: or i intentionally didn' t care :)

Comment: What is your progress in installing a complete new eclipse on a complete new workspace and import your project there. Would`t you be able to continue to work then? Or are you just keen on solving this particular problem with this particular eclipse configuration you are having?

Comment: It says the same error message when I try to start it on a completely new workspace...

Comment: I just updated the log file now by renaming the old one, so I get a new one. I updated the log file on the page too.

Comment: Where did you install eclipse in your filesystem? What path?

Comment: I never installed it, I got it from a video for "how to make mods for minecraft".

Comment: So, I have it in my downloads folder.

Comment: Ok, where did the eclipse come from. Where have you downloaded it from? Could you please try to download an Eclipse from here: https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/ and try to open that one? Because somehow i feel you got a corrupted eclipse.